# Using Multiple Tables in a Zend Model and returning a combined result set

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi This is either a very specific or very generic quetion - I'm not sure, and I'm new to the Zend framework / oo generally.  Please be patient if this is a stupid Q...

Anyway, I want to create a model which does something like:

```
Read all the itmes from a table 'gifts' into a row set

for each row in the table, read from a second table which shows how many have been bought, the append this as another "field" in the returned row

return the row set, with the number bought included.
```

Most of the simple Zend examples seem to only use one table in a model, but my reading seems to suggest that I should do most of the work there, rather than in the controller.  If this is too generic a question, any example of a model that works with 2 tables and returns an array would be great!

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi Brian, tx for the response.  Iit's exactly what I'm trying to do, but i can't get the 

    $select = $this->getAdapter()->select()

Part.  I know this is trying to get the connection to the db, but i just cant make it work, can you point me at something which explains how to reference the db?

Answer (score 2):

I assume second tables is something like "gift_order" or something.

In this case you need to specify tables relationships beetween "gift" and and "gift_order" via foreign keys and describe it in table class.

```
It will look like this

    class GiftOrder extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
    /** Table name */
    protected $_name    = 'gif_order';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
    "Fileset" =>array(
        "columns" => array("gifId"),
        "refTableClass" => "Gift",
        "refColumns" => array("id")
    ));
      ........................

You need to specify foreigh key constraint while create table with SQL
      ALTER TABLE `gift_order`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `order_to_gift` FOREIGN KEY (`giftId`) REFERENCES `gift` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If this is something you looking for you could find more on this at this link [link http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html)

With such solution you will be able to loop gifts and get their orders without any  complex SQL's

$rowSetGifts = $this->findGifts();

```
while($rowSetGifts->next()){
   $gift = $rowSetGifts->current();
   $orders = $gift->findGiftOrder();//This is magick methods, this is the same $gift->findDependentRowset('GiftOrder');
```

//Now you can do something with orders - count($orders), loop them or edit

}

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a function in your gifts model class that returns what you want.  It would probably look something like:

```
public function getGiftWithAdditionalField($giftId) {
  $select = $this->getAdapter()->select()
    ->from(array('g' => 'gifts'))
    ->joinLeft(array('table2' => 't2'), 'g.gift_id = t2.gift_id', array('field' => 'field'))
    ->where('g.gift_id = ?', $giftId);
  return $this->getAdapter->fetchAll($select);
}
```

You can check out the [Zend Framework Docs on Joins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join) for more info.

Comment: I was going to link to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html until I reread the question and saw that only the extra field was needed.